# Read values from URL parameter where slashes are represented by %2F in PHP

Tags: php, date, variables, strip

The datepicker I'm using passes the date to a php script on form submit.

The URL parameter is as follows - datepicker1=12%2F09%2F2014

I can store 12%2F09%2F2014 in a variable.

```
$datepicker1 = $_GET['datepicker1'];
```

I also have 3 other variables namely:
    $day
    $month
    $year

How do add individual day, month, and year to their respective variables by extracting them from variable $datepicker1?

Comment: Are you sure `$datepicker1` contains `%2F` sequences? They appear in the URL because `/` is a special character in URLs but they should be decoded when `$_GET[]` is populated. Use `DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $datepicker1);` to work with the value.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the JQuery datepicker. I can urldecode the variable to get 12/09/2014. But then, how do I get 12 to $day, 09 to $month, and 2014 to $year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$datepicker1 = "12%2F09%2F2014";
$val =  urldecode($datepicker1);
$array = explode('/', $val);
print_r($array);
```

The $array variable is your result.
Now you can assign array value into your  $day, $month, $year variable like this:

```
$day = $array[0];
$month = $array[1];
$year = $array[2];
```

Now you can store it into database.
I hope this will helpful for you.
Thanks

Comment: Helpful and useful. Thanks. Also tried substr which works too.

Answer (score 0):

use this urldecode() function

```
$date =  urldecode("12%2F09%2F2014");

$year = date('Y', strtotime($date));
$mon = date('m', strtotime($date));
$day = date('d', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Once I have 12/09/2014 from decode, how do I add 12 to $day, 09 to $month, and 2014 to $year? Is it possible to use trim? I'm looking for the best solution to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `sbstr()` to get the value.

Suppose for date `$date=substr($datepicker1,0,2);`

Similarly others.. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$date= urldecode("12%2F09%2F2014");
echo substr($date, 0, 2);
echo "<br>";

echo substr($date, 3, 2);
echo "<br>";

 echo substr($date, 6, 4);
 echo "<br>";
```

I tried the above and it seems to work fine for me.

Instead of echo-ing - will add these to variables.

The array solution provided by Yash also works.